# Term for something you don't know you'll like until you discover it?

Tags: word-choice

There is a situation where a person has no idea that something is exactly what they are looking for, desire or like until they discover it.

Is there a term for something you don't know you'll like until you discover it?

Comment: Should you find such a word, I would find it to be itself an excellent example of what it describes.

Comment: ...it would be **autological**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, [**serendipity**](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/serendipity) is the act of finding something valuable or delightful when you are not looking for it.

I'm not aware of a related concrete / more concrete noun for the object found or the idea the person has.

Comment: "A serendipitous discovery" is a term I have encountered a few times. It would fit the bill I guess, but the number of people that understand the term is pretty low. If I were to throw it around in a casual conversation I would get a lot of blank stares. Even from people who are native speakers.

Answer (score 6):

There are also the fairly common phrases **pleasant surprise** and **pleasantly surprised**. (But not as succinct as Edwin Ashworth's *serendipity*)

Comment: But I'd usually choose them!

Answer (score 1):

If it is something which one learns to appreciate, '**an acquired taste'** fits the bill.

'I didn't know anything about India Pale Ale until I acquired a taste for it.' When my wife persuaded me to listen to *The Archers*, I found that I acquired a taste for it every day'.

Comment: This seems like the opposite word he's looking for. You 'acquire a taste' for something if you don't like it at first, and then learn to like it over time. He's asking for something he doesn't know about, but when he tries it he likes it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not perfect, but how about "a hidden gem"?